# Precompile jsx for React in django-compressor

Tags: node.js, django, reactjs, babeljs, django-compressor

Using Cygwin on Windows 10 (64 bits)
Installed `babel-cli`, `react` and `babel-preset-react` on top of Node.js, which was installed via Windows Installer (since there is no support for Cygwin.) I installed those Node packages using `yarn`, in the global modules folder.

In the `django-compressor` documentation (https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reactjs/) they say that a precompiler setting does the trick:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
   ('text/jsx', 'cat {infile} | babel > {outfile}'),
)
```

However, babel is not recognizing `jsx` (throwing errors when encountering virtual dom elements.) It's obvious because I am not passing the `react` preset to the command. But there is no way I can use that preset because I installed in the global module folder and now I am unable to make babel find and use it.

I need one of these possible solutions:

1. How can I make babel use a preset globally installed (how should I use `babel --presets react` in a way that works)?
2. How do I use a `.babelrc` file in a Django project?
3. If I were to install the preset locally (which I seem to dislike a lot) how do I make it live with my Django project without making mess out of my project directory structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I banged my head a few times and found a solution:

1. There is no way to make babel work with presets installed globally. It is mandatory to install them locally. All `react`, `react-dom`, `babel-core`, `babel-loader`, `babel-preset-react` (and perhaps `babel-preset-es2015` if latest ECMA syntax is desired) must be installed locally.
2. There is no place to put a `.babelrc` file where the precompiler would use it. No use to have a `babel` section in `package.json` either. Instead, the precompiler setting should pass the presets in command line like:

   ```
   COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
     ('text/jsx', 'cat {infile} | babel --presets react,es2015 > {outfile}'),
   )
   ```
3. Just assume that the folder where `manage.py` lives is also the root for Nodejs packages. Not tested when deployed and running from a `wsgi` file but maybe the `wsgi` should also live next to `manage.py`.

Also, it looks like all these files and folders: <s>`node_modules`</s>, `package.json` and `yarn.lock` (if installing with `yarn` as I am,) must be included in version control.

**EDITED:**
I no loger think `node_modules` should go into version control.